# Gradio : Login System. How to get a fully functional Login system on Gradio?

Tags: authentication, chatbot, gradio

I am building a Gradio Chat Interface where I need to authenticate before using the chatbot. Gradio provides its own authentication, which is limited. So, I want to have a fully functional login system with access tokens, refresh tokens (with expiration and renewing time), and logout functionality.

Would you please suggest me how could I achieve that using only Gradio and Python?

If I need to use any other framework to achieve this, could you please suggest me any Python framework that would be more compatible with Gradio?

```
import gradio as gr
import random
import time

def authenticate(username, password):
    if username == USERNAME and password == PASSWORD:
        return True
        
    else:
        return False

def logout(request: gr.Request):

    print("logged out")

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot()
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    clear = gr.ClearButton([msg, chatbot])
    logout_button = gr.Button(value = "Logout")
    logout_button.click(logout)
    # logout_button = gr.LogoutButton()
    def respond(message, chat_history):
        bot_message = random.choice(["How are you?", "I'm very hungry"])
        chat_history.append((message, bot_message))
        time.sleep(2)
        return "", chat_history

    msg.submit(respond, [msg, chatbot], [msg, chatbot])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.launch(auth=authenticate,share=True)
```